# Invalid variable referenced in @include directive

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js, graphql-tag

I'll duplicate my [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-anywhere/issues/90) here hoping that someone may give me a hint to where I'm going wrong.

Here's the schema on GraphCool:

```js
type Reservation implements Node {
  createdAt: DateTime!
    id: ID!@isUnique
  updatedAt: DateTime!
    user: User @relation(name: "UserReservations")
}

type User implements Node {
  createdAt: DateTime!
    id: ID!@isUnique
  updatedAt: DateTime!
    reservations: [Reservation!] !@relation(name: "UserReservations")
}
```

Here's a fragment in my Angular code:

```js
fragment reservation on Reservation {
  id,
  user @include(
    if :$is_admin) {
    id
  }
}
```

Here's my GraphQL query:

```js
mutation($id: ID!, $is_admin: Boolean = true) {
  createReservation(userId: $id) {
    ...reservation
  }
}
$ {
  RESERVATION_FRAGMENT.reservation
}
```

Calling the above mutation using `apollo.watchQuery` executes successfully on GraphCool, but the client produces the following error:

```js
Error: Invalid variable referenced in @include directive.
at directives.js: 42
at Array.some( < anonymous > )
at Object.shouldInclude(directives.js: 20)
at graphql.js: 27
at Array.forEach( < anonymous > )
at executeSelectionSet(graphql.js: 26)
at graphql.js: 55
at Array.forEach( < anonymous > )
at executeSelectionSet(graphql.js: 26)
at graphql.js: 94
```

Comment: Same problem trying to read my query in the update callback of my mutation